# Rails balance withdraw action threading issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord, mutex, banking

To allow users create balance withdrawal request, I have a `WithdrawalsController#create` action. The code checks if the user has sufficient balance before proceeding to creating the withdrawal.

```
def create
  if amount > current_user.available_balance
    error! :bad_request, :metadata => {code: "002", description: "insufficient balance"}
    return
  end

  withdrawal = current_user.withdrawals.create(amount: amount, billing_info: current_user.billing_info)
  exposes withdrawal
end
```

This can pose a serious issue in a multi-threaded server. When two create requests arrive simultaneously, and both requests pass the the balance check before creating the withdrawal, then both withdrawal can be created even if the sum of two could be exceeding the original balance.

Having a class variable of `Mutex` will not be a good solution because that will lock this action for all users, where a lock on a per-user level is desired.

What is the best solution for this?

The following diagram illustrates my suspected threading issue, could it be occurring in Rails?
[image: Balance Withdrawal Threading Issue]

Comment: Where the multi threading issue could occur on your code? What the `exposes` method do?

Comment: @Marwen, as mentioned on  this [post](https://bearmetal.eu/theden/how-do-i-know-whether-my-rails-app-is-thread-safe-or-not/): "Rails creates a new controller object of every HTTP request". So I believe in servers like Passenger, these different requests are processed in different threads? `exposes` is just to return the withdrawal object, I'm using `Rocket Pants` gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell your code is safe here, mutlithreading is not a much of a problem. Even with more app instances generate by your **app server**, each instance will end up testing `amount > current_user.available_balance`.
If you are really paranoiac about it. you could wrap the all with a `transacaction`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  withdrawal = current_user.withdrawals.create!(
    amount: amount,
    billing_info: current_user.billing_info
  )

  # if after saving the `available_balance` goes under 0
  # the hole transaction will be rolled back and any
  # change happened to the database will be undone.
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if current_user.available_balance < 0
end
```

Comment: I've updated the question to illustrate more clearly of my doubt on the threading issue. Are you saying that that case will not occur at all?